# Realm opens 4 times on Login

Tags: swift, realm, kotlin-multiplatform, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I have a app that checks when loggin in the type of user, to know where to navigate.

Whenver I do the login, in the logs, the realm will open 4 times.

My login View:

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @State var userId : String = ""
    @State var password : String = ""
    @State var goToNextScreen : Int? = nil
    @State var myIsUser = false
    @State var myUser = UserInfo()
    
       
    var repo = RealmRepo()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            VStack(){
    
                TextField("Username", text: $userId)

                TextField("Password", text: $password)
                      

                Button("Login"){
  
                    repo.login(email: $userId.wrappedValue, password: $password.wrappedValue) { user, error in
                                                
                        if(user != nil){
                            
                            
                            self.repo.getUserProfile(userId: user?.id as! String).watch(block:  {items in
                                
                                self.myUser = items as! UserInfo
                                
                                                                
                                if(self.myUser.typeOfUser != true){
                                    print("this user type 1")
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUser")
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")
                                    myIsUser=false
                                }else{
                                    print("this is user type2")
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUser")
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")
                                    myIsUser=true
                                }
                                goToNextScreen=1
                            })
                            
                            
                        }else{
                            print("login failed")
                        }
                        
                       
                    }
                    
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: myIsUser ? AnyView(View1().navigationBarHidden(true)) : AnyView(View2().navigationBarHidden(true)) , tag: 1, selection: $goToNextScreen){
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only this part of code will print 4 times the log: `INFO: [REALM] Realm opened:  /var/mobile/`
This part just checks the login and goes to a view.

How is this possible?

Is it because the the login block?
Should I make the login and getUserProfile calls in a different way?

The repo.login method:

```
suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): User {
        return appService.login(Credentials.emailPassword(email, password))
    }
```

The repo.getUserProfile() that will return the type of the user:

```
fun getUserProfile(userId: String): CommonFlow<UserInfo?> {
        val user = realm.query<UserInfo>("_id = $0", userId).asFlow().map {
            it.list.firstOrNull()
        }.asCommonFlow()

        return user
    }
enter code here
```

I ve uploaded a reproduction scenario: [tmpfiles.org/1031395/mongo-conference-master3.zip](https://tmpfiles.org/1031395/mongo-conference-master3.zip)

It is the same as the repository from mongodb [github.com/mongodb-developer/mongo-conference](https://github.com/mongodb-developer/mongo-conference), just with the getUserProfile changed with return CommonFlow

Comment: Make the repo variable a State variable

Comment: Nothing changed unfortunately, still prints multiple `realm opened`

Comment: I think its because that I call the getUserProfile inside the login, how can I solve this?

Comment: There is no way to tell with the code you have provided, my guess is that the view is getting recreated somehow

Comment: RealmRepo() is being called in every view it seems like, they are all different instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very simple explanation why realm opens several time: `Realm.open` call is inside `RealmRepo` instance and you are creating multiple `RealmRepo` instances.

For instance SwiftUI recreates `RealmRepo` with every state change. Also other views e.g. `HomeView` creates its own  `RealmRepo` and so on.

There are a lot of different ways to fix it. Here is some of them:

#### Make your `RealmRepo` object

Just change `class RealmRepo` to `object RealmRepo`. That will make your `RealmRepo` a singleton in your iOS code you can access it like this:

```swift
var repo = RealmRepo.shared
```

#### Use `EnvironmentObject`

There is a simple Dependency Injection mechanism in SwiftUI that can help you use single instance of RealmRepo.

In your `iOSApp.swift`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct iOSApp: App {
    @StateObject var repo = RealmRepo()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LoginScreenView()
              .environmentObject(repo)
        }
    }
}
```

and in all child views `Login`, `HomeView`, etc. use:

```swift
@EnvironmentObject var repo: RealmRepo
```

and do not create new instances.

More about `@EnvironmentObject` you can read [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views)

#### Use some DI frameworks

You can use some DI frameworks, e.g. [Koin](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views) and specify `RealmRepo` as singleton where when inject in iOS app.

#### Refactor `RealmRepo`

You can change how `realm` field initialized in `RealmRepo`. For example you can extract logic that opens Realm in a singleton:

```kotlin
class RealmRepo {
// ...
    private val appService by lazy {
        RealmHolder.appService
    }

    private val realm by lazy {
        RealmHolder.realm
    }
// ...
}

object RealmHolder {
    private val schemaClass = setOf(UserInfo::class, SessionInfo::class, ConferenceInfo::class)

    val appService by lazy {
        val appConfiguration =
            AppConfiguration.Builder(appId = "rconfernce-vkrny").log(LogLevel.ALL).build()
        App.create(appConfiguration)
    }

    val realm by lazy {
        val user = appService.currentUser!!

        val config =
            SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, schemaClass).name("conferenceInfo").schemaVersion(1)
                .initialSubscriptions { realm ->
                    add(realm.query<UserInfo>(), name = "user info", updateExisting = true)
                    add(realm.query<SessionInfo>(), name = "session info", updateExisting = true)
                    add(
                        realm.query<ConferenceInfo>(),
                        name = "conference info",
                        updateExisting = true
                    )
                }.waitForInitialRemoteData().build()
        Realm.open(config)
    }
}
```